# mysql REGEXP exact pattern match

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I'm working on writing a php script that will loop through all tables in database and look for plain text credit card numbers. For this I'm using MySQL REGEXP. I need only those results which "only" contains credit card numbers. If there is any textual data that contains credit card number then the script should not consider it.

e.g.

|   id   |        ccno        |
|   1   |        4111111111111111        |
|   2   |        4111 1111 1111 1111    |
|   3   |        4111-1111-1111-1111   |
|   4   | some text 4111111111111111 some text |

If the query is trieggered on above table then it should return first 3 records, it should not return 4th record. For this purpose I'm using below query and the issue I'm facing is the query is returning all the 4 records.

```
SELECT ccno FROM aacc WHERE 
(ccno = REGEXP '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
OR ccno = REGEXP '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
OR ccno = REGEXP '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
```

Comment: Don't you also want to verify the "check digit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are known complex regular expressions to match card numbers from the large credit card providers, such as Visa and MasterCard.  For the purpose of your question, the following pattern comes close to what you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ccno REGEXP '^[0-9]{4}([[:space:]-]?[0-9]{4}){3}$';
```

### Demo

This pattern is not exact, but then again none of your data matches, for example, Amex cards, which have the format of `dddd-dddddd-ddddd`, with two dashes, not three.  If you plan on doing this with production data, you should research how to match credit card numbers with regex.

https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html

Answer (score 2):

Try regex `^([0-9]{4}[-[:space:]]?){4}$`

This will match the 16 numbers separated by space or hyphen optionally

[regex](https://regex101.com/r/AHXcBM/5)

Comment: This is working fine for 16 digits but how to match 15 digit cards?

Comment: @Suyog If you have a serious need to validate credit numbers, then should [read here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/creditcard.html); this is a problem which has already been tackled many times already.

Comment: Yes, Thanks @ran_0315

Answer (score 0):

Though above two answers helped me in what I was looking for, I've now wrote entire query that will give exact match for plain text credit cards. 
Cards that are working fine for this query are:
American Express
Visa
MasterCard
Discover

The MySQL query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE (ccno REGEXP '^4[0-9]{3}([[:space:]-]?[0-9]{4}){3}$'
       OR ccno REGEXP '^3[47][0-9]{2}[[:space:]-]?[0-9]{6}[[:space:]-]?[0-9]{5}$'
       OR ccno REGEXP '^6011([[:space:]-]?[0-9]{4}){3}$'
       OR ccno REGEXP '^65[0-9]{2}([[:space:]-]?[0-9]{4}){3}$'
       OR ccno REGEXP '^5[1-5][0-9]{2}([[:space:]-]?[0-9]{4}){3}$'
       OR ccno REGEXP '^222[1-9]([[:space:]-]?[0-9]{4}){3}$'
       OR ccno REGEXP '^2[3-6][0-9]{2}([[:space:]-]?[0-9]{4}){3}$'
       OR ccno REGEXP '^27[01][0-9]([[:space:]-]?[0-9]{4}){3}$'
       OR ccno REGEXP '^2720([[:space:]-]?[0-9]{4}){3}$'
       );
```

Working example can be seen [here](http://rextester.com/DYPJW56236).